# Como usar @Html.ActionLink para criar links para uma Rota de vários seguimentos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu gostaria de usar o @Html.ActionLink para criar o seguinte link:

```
http://localhost:59278/video/categoria/new-movies/3
```

Sendo que meu controle é:

```
[Route("video/categoria/new-movies/{page?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page)
{

}
```

Eu sei usar o `@Html.ActionLink` passando parâmetros, mas no caso o parâmetro page é parte da rota.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está utilizando o [Attribute Routing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/), então lembrando apenas que você deve chamar o método [MapMvcAttributeRoutes()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.routecollectionattributeroutingextensions.mapmvcattributeroutes?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) seu `RouteConfig` com a seguinte linha:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Feito isso, basta adicionar o atributo em seu `controller`, da mesma forma que você está fazendo.

```
[Route("video/categoria/new-movies/{page?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page)
{

}
```

Até essa parte eu suponho que você já possui, então agora vamos ao seu [ActionLink()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

```
@Html.ActionLink("TEXTO","Index","CONTROLLER",  new { page = 3 }, null)
```

Lembrando que seu `actionLink` "trabalha" da seguinte forma:

```
MvcHtmlString HtmlHelper.ActionLink(
    string linkText, 
    string actionName, 
    string controllerName, 
    object routeValues, 
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

A "grosso modo", em primeiro lugar você passa o texto, depois a `Action`, o `Controller`, os valores de rota e atributos html.

> Como pode ver, no `ActionLink` "você não se preocupa" com as rotas, chame apenas a **Action** e o **Controller**, lembrando de passar os parâmetros necessários.

Comment: Funcionou, agora, quando eu coloco uma variável a mais no controle , `string sort` e uma a mais no HTML.ActionLink `new { page = 3, sort = "newest" }` ele gera a url assim: `http://localhost:59278/video/categoria/new-movies/3?sort=newest`.. Não deveria gerar assim: `http://localhost:59278/video/categoria/new-movies/3/newest`? O que fiz de errado?

Comment: Se você mudar somente no `ActionLink` ele irá adicionar como queryString. Para evitar isso, você deve alterar a sua rota, mais ou mesmo assim: `[Route("video/categoria/new-movies/{page?}/{sort}")]`

Comment: Pois é, eu fiz isso tb... esqueci de colocar `        [Route("video/categoria/{categoria}/{page?}/{sort?}")]` mas ele não funcionou não... Estranho

Comment: Repare que você está passando a categoria como parâmetro `{categoria}`, e não como valor fixo `/categoria/`.

Comment: Putz, to alterando o metodo errado, deu certo, obrigado!